# TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAfter' of undefined

Tags: webpack, next.js, typeerror, node-modules, insertafter

When i try to run the frontend of my project (which is in next.js) with 'yarn dev', it throws me this error:

```
error - ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[2]!./styles/global.css

TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAfter' of undefined
```

according to what I've found until now, the error is most probably related to webpack
I've found similar issues (not the exact issue) here on:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/23795

and

https://github.com/thetinywebagency/thetinywebagency.github.io/issues/1

Solutions mentioned in these 2 links didn't help in my case.
If someone has solved the problem, assist needed...

Comment: `npm update`. can help.

Comment: @Marcio it didn't help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to tailwind `error - ./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/css-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].oneOf[6].use[2]!./styles/global.css`

check your `./styles/global.css`